# Apply udf element-wise in any-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, user-defined-functions

So I have the following function which given an array of numbers removes the outliers:

```
def reject_outliers(data, m = 1):
    d = np.abs(data - np.median(data))
    mdev = np.median(d)
    s = d/mdev if mdev else 0
    return np.array(data)[s<m]

vec_reject_outliers = np.vectorize(reject_outliers)
```

I would like to apply this function element-wise in multiple multidimensional arrays. In the following example I try to find the mean of each element between the 3 nested arrays in the list:

```
a = np.array([np.array([4000, np.array([12,10])]), np.array([50, np.array([13, 11])]), np.array([51,np.array([30,20])])])

result = [vec_reject_outliers(l, m = 1).mean(axis = 0) for l in zip(*a)]
```

The `result` should be `[51, array([13, 11])]` since certain numbers will be treated as outliers and thus removed from the calculation. Yet the result that I get is `[1367.0, array([18.33333333, 13.66666667])]` which is the mean calculated without omitting any element.

Is there a way to perform `reject_outliers` element wise in such scenarios or any other way I can achieve the expected `result` between any-dimentional arrays?

Comment: Where's your multidimensional array?  What's the shape of `a`?  Looks like 1d with object dtype.  `vectorize` just iterate on the outer array.  Why not just use a list comprehension?

Comment: I would like this function to work between any multidimensional arrays wrought knowing their dimensions in advance. Inside a are the 3 multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Your `a` is 2d.  Some elements are scalar, others are 1d.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `print` to your function to see exactly what data gets sent to it:

```
In [65]: def reject_outliers(data, m = 1):
    ...:     print('data',data)
    ...:     d = np.abs(data - np.median(data))
    ...:     mdev = np.median(d)
    ...:     s = d/mdev if mdev else 0
    ...:     return np.array(data)[s<m]
    ...: 
In [66]: vec_reject_outliers = np.vectorize(reject_outliers)
In [67]: result = [vec_reject_outliers(l, m = 1).mean(axis = 0) for l in zip(*a)]
data 4000              # trial run to determine otypes
data 4000
data 50
data 51
data 12           # trial run for 2nd tuple
data 12
data 10
data 13
data 11
data 30
data 20
```

So each call to `reject` is an element.  That's what you wanted right?

> apply this function element-wise in multiple multidimensional arrays

But let's look at your array

```
In [68]: a
Out[68]: 
array([[4000, array([12, 10])],
       [50, array([13, 11])],
       [51, array([30, 20])]], dtype=object)
In [69]: a.shape
Out[69]: (3, 2)
In [70]: a[:,0]
Out[70]: array([4000, 50, 51], dtype=object)
In [71]: a[:,1]
Out[71]: array([array([12, 10]), array([13, 11]), array([30, 20])], dtype=object)
```

And the `l` being passed to `vec...` - two tuples

```
In [77]: list(zip(*a))
Out[77]: [(4000, 50, 51), (array([12, 10]), array([13, 11]), array([30, 20]))]
```

So `vec...` is called twice, once with each of these 2 arrays:

```
In [82]: np.array(Out[77][0])
Out[82]: array([4000,   50,   51])
In [83]: np.array(Out[77][1])
Out[83]: 
array([[12, 10],
       [13, 11],
       [30, 20]])
```

In turn it calls `reject...` with the elements of `Out[82]` and then with the elements of `Out[83]`.

I haven't tried to figure out exactly what `reject...` does, or what it should be passed, but apparently `vectorize` is not working as you want.  I'd suggest dropping that and doing an explicit iteration.  That way you have more control.

---

Using `reject` in the comprehension:

```
In [84]: result = [reject_outliers(l, m = 1).mean(axis = 0) for l in zip(*a)]
data (4000, 50, 51) 1
data (array([12, 10]), array([13, 11]), array([30, 20])) 1
In [85]: result
Out[85]: [51.0, 12.0]
```

Applying `reject` separately to the 2nd column of `a`:

```
In [87]: result = [reject_outliers(l, m = 1).mean(axis = 0) for l in zip(*a[:,1])]
data (12, 13, 30) 1
data (10, 11, 20) 1
In [88]: result
Out[88]: [13.0, 11.0]
```

And using the 1st column of `a` directly:

```
In [91]: reject_outliers(a[:,0], m = 1).mean(axis = 0)
data [4000 50 51] 1
Out[91]: 51.0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I actually wanted the `result` to be the following [51, array([13, 11])]. This will be calculated as follows. 4000, 50, 51 will be given as input to `reject_outliers` which will output 51, then 12,13,30 will be given as input to `reject_outliers` which will output 13 and finally 10, 11,20 will be given as input to `reject_outliers` which will output 11 thus the final result would be [51, array([13, 11])] which has the same shape of the 3 nested arrays in a.

Comment: I can get those numbers by calling `reject...` directly, but handling `a[:,0]` and `a[:,1]` separately.  Only the 2nd works with the `zip`.